# Point in Polygon Add Polygon Value

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, attribute-joins

I have a file of points with Easting and Northing. I have a 1km grid table. Both have the same projection and I can see in a map where the points are layered over the grid squares.

What I need is to find the Grid Square ID that the points fall into.

I have tried all sort of things, nothing I have found in forums/google or QGIS seems to be what I need.

I'm using QGIS Las Palmas.

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Intersection.

   From: Vector> Geoprocessing Tools> Intersection
2. Join attributes by location.

   From: Vector> Data Management Tools> Join attributes by location

If grids in Grid Square layer don't have any unique ID (or sth like that), add new field to the layer for unique value, so that, after any processes pointed above, you will get that which point is in which grid. Because QGIS doesn't automatically add any unique ID field. (ArcGIS adds a field named OBJECTID)

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about @KadirŞahbaz "Join attributes by location" doesn't use any id's it uses the spatial relationship of the features.

Comment: That is exactly the question. "Join attributes by location" will take the point, and join all of the polygon attributes based on the spatial relationship. This will tag the polygon ID to the point.